# How can I call a recursive function in reverse order?

Tags: java, recursion

I was asked an interview question stating that: How can you print a number from one to the supplied parameter number to a recursive function?

Say the function name is **recursiveFunc**. When I call it like

```
recursiveFunc(100);
```

it should print 1, 2, 3 to 100 and so on.

Note it should not use any other helping initializing, etc. variable.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does this have to do with "reverse order"?

Comment: It has to do. It is just a small trick but evil. Like you do some thing and then call itself. But in this case you first call itself and then do something which make it reverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void recursiveFunc(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) 
       return;
    recursiveFunc(n-1); 
    System.out.println(n); 
}
```

Print after recursion.

Answer (score 6):

Just print the value after recursing

```
public void recursiveFunc(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) return;
    recursiveFunc(n-1); // recurses 
    System.out.println(n); // prints 1 first 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like:

```
void recursiveFunc(int n)
{
     if (n == 0)
     {
         return;
     }
     recursiveFunc(n-1);
     System.out.println(n);
}
```

Comment: This is not ascending. This will print descending order. like 100,99,98

Comment: No. It will print from 1 to 100. You are first moving down the stack from 100 to 1 and then you are printing. Hence it will print from 1 to 100